# Webpack can't load Higher Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I've created a Higher Order Component that looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export const ForceMobileHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

But webpack is giving the error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (45:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     render() {
>       return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
|     }
|   }
```

And here's the relevant Webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /core-js/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: './webpack_cache/'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've made HOCs before but never run into something like this. What could be going on?

Comment: It seems to be getting confused by JSX. What does your webpack config look like? In particular, what loader are you using for `.jsx` files (or whatever file extension this file has)?

Comment: @NicholasTower Good point. Updated question with Webpack config...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the import. I was trying to import `ForceMobileHOC.JS` instead of `ForceMobileHOC.js`. Not sure why the error looked like it did, but that was the solution.